# iPhone Photos app adds random people to the people album

Tags: iphone, photos, photos.app

When I take photos of a crowded place, I often get random strangers in the shot, facing in my direction. The iPhone Photos app then adds these strangers to the **People** album.

How can I remove these strangers? The only solution I’ve found was to hide the photo, but that hides it from Moments, which I don't want.

I'm using an iPhone 6, iOS 10.3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from the **People** album, tap *Select* in the top-right corner. Next select all the faces you don't know, then tap `Hide` in the bottom-left corner.

This will hide those people from your **People** album without hiding the photos themselves.

Answer (score 0):

In the People album (where all the faces are shown), choose the Select button at the top-right, then select the people to remove and choose Remove in the bottom-left.